# How to use a self-signed public certificate in Mule ESB WSC?

Tags: web-services, mule, ssl-certificate

I have one .cer file which is a self-signed public certificate. I have added it in a truststore, configured it in a https connector, and referenced it in the WSC component. But while trying to run the code, I am getting a "no trusted certificate found error". Do I need to configure keystore or anything else?

Comment: Hi, you need to add way more details. Paste you mule config and all can be usefull, off course mask password if they are sensitive.

Comment: Yes, more details would help.  Specifically: include the mule configuration XML for the https:connector or http:listener-config you are using, include the Mule configuration for the https:inbound-endpoint or http:listener, include the version of Mule ESB you are running, include the location of your truststore, and explain how you are sending the HTTPS request to the Mule flow.

Comment: When ever you are using trust store then it means you are using 2 way ssl and yes you need to use the keystore as well. If you are using the one way ssl then you need to use the keystore and only that helps.

Comment: HI Naveen Raj.Am new to this certificates I just have 3 certificates and creating a keystore just with that is fine?

Comment: I undeleted Erwin Bolwidit

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certs can be used by the `<tls:context>` component. After configuration you're able to use it for http other other supported components.

```
<tls:context name="customContext">
    <tls:trust-store path="/etc/mule/tls/.." password="yourPass"/>
    <tls:key-store path="/etc/mule/tls/.." keyPassword="yourKeyPass" password="yourPass"/>
 </tls:context>
```

More can be found at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/tls-configuration